# mysql -v ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, magento2, zsh

I need help. When Checking mySQL version I get this error. I do not use mysql a lot and I am trying to set up a Magento store through command line.  However, first I am trying to set up mySql from the database.  I am using Mac OS Catalina and Zsh terminal.

Error.

```
mysql -v
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I know it must be something with my database but I am confused. Any help would be appreciated. When I try to download Magento 2 setup install I get this similar error.

```
 --db-user=root --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=123123q --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

In InstallCommand.php line 264:

  Parameter validation failed
```

EDIT: However, When I connect to `mysql -u root` I can connect to the database no problem.

Comment: you need to grant privileges to the root user. 

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`

Comment: This pretty much did it.  Thank you.  I had to go into the php myadmin console. Create a new user grant all privileges on that user. This link also gave me a clue on how to solve it.  Thank you for the help!
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153562/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-using-password-yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the user and password when running mysql from the command line

mysql -u root -p
[enter password]

Alternatively, you can set up a mylogin.cnf (or a .my.cnf) to save the user/password as a file, so you don't need to remember it.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86595/how-can-i-make-mysql-client-read-password-from-mylogin-cnf

Comment: This I can do.  I can enter into mysql queries. However, when I type mysql -v I get the same error. Not sure why.  I did download mysql through brew.